# Minimize Qt folder size after compilation

Tags: visual-studio, qt, size, directory, erase

I had to compile by myself Qt libraries (both 4.8.6 and 5.5.1 version) using Visual Studio (2008 and 2013).

After this I need to share built libraries to other co-workers, zipping the folder and putting it in a ftp server. So I'd like to remove all unnecessary stuff and maintain only the necessary in order to use Qt.

At this moment I've removed:

- all .obj files
- doc folder

What other stuff can I delete in order to minimize the qt folder size? I don't need to recompile it again. Can I delete the src/ folder for example?

Answer (score 1):

Use `nmake clean` (or possibly `nmake /f makefile.vc clean`).